# Изменить размеры балуна

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Внутри балуна есть спрятанный контейнер (display:none), по клику на кнопку открывается этот контейнер (display:block), НО размер балуна остается прежним и часть контента не видно.

Вопрос: как обновить балун (размеры балуна)?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Можно пример где не сработало?

Comment: @se0ga https://jsfiddle.net/Agapkin/de1gq3sc/

Comment: @se0ga Есть идеи как победить? Или это колхоз? Сейчас по кнопке подробно всплывает окно, хочется избавиться от него.

Comment: Как насчёт того, чтобы просто менять данные внутри балуна https://jsfiddle.net/L6f30yg5/ ?

Answer (score 0):

В песочнице Яндекса есть [пример](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/balloon_autopan) пользовательского макета балуна с поддержкой автопозиционирования.

В нём предлагается создание собственного балуна с использованием фабрики [templateLayoutFactory](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/templateLayoutFactory.html).

Чтобы балун автоматически подстраивался под размер содержимого, необходимо правильно оповещать о его текущих размерах. Для этого необходимо реализовать метод getShape().

Но эффективней будет просто менять данные внутри балуна, как посоветовали в комментариях.